# Model Field from DropDownList with Scaffolding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, scaffolding

In my Model, I want to be able to select a property's value through a DropDownList. Like this:

```
public int Foo { get; set; }

private IEnumerable<string> FooOptions = new IEnumerable<string> { "Foo", "Bar" };
```

So, in the rendered html, I'd have something such as:

```
<select name="Foo">
    <option value="0">Foo</option>
    <option value="1">Bar</option>
</select>
```

This would be quite easy to do in the Controller and View, but I actually am searching for a way for this to work with Visual Studio's default Controller / View Scaffolder.

Is it even possible? Or even better, is there a better way to achieve this?

TIA, André

Comment: seems you are facing a problem with mvc scaffolding of your dropdown. Seems like your needs are straight forward and can be done with scaffolding. so whats the problem youre running into?

Comment: I actually wanna know how can that be achieved trough scaffolding. Is there any kind of standard or convention to do this? (BTW, I am actually looking for Visual Studio's default scaffolding with the "Add Controller" dialog, not MvcScaffolding. The first one's results are better IMO.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this link: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/examining-how-aspnet-mvc-scaffolds-the-dropdownlist-helper

You'll notice, if you are using MVC with EF against a Model utilizing a foreign key (convert into a POCO with an IEnumerable), Visual Studio will automatically create a dropdownlist.

Comment: Hmm... so the best way to do this would be to change `FooOptions` into a new Model, and, say, seed it in the application's startup if needed?

Comment: Yes, exactly. you only need to seed it if you have no data to start. but you have the idea right.

Comment: Got it. I just tought there could be a faster or simpler way to do it, but this definitely works. Accepting as answer.